# gtkmm4 building in Ubuntu 22.04 : Ninja : Unknown IO error

Tags: 22.04

```
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-4.8.0$ meson setup --prefix /usr --libdir lib your_builddir .
The Meson build system
Version: 1.3.0
Source dir: /home/raphy/gtkmm-4.8.0
Build dir: /home/raphy/gtkmm-4.8.0/your_builddir
```

For size limits I've put the entire output of `meson setup --prefix /usr --libdir lib your_builddir .` command in google drive : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvP_xitHnRaVyNmXLOy7ZBtjdP1zZyev/view?usp=drive_link

Execuing ninja got this error:

```
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-4.8.0/your_builddir$ ninja
[125/2744] Generating subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/manual_html with a custom command
FAILED: subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/html 
/usr/bin/python3 /home/raphy/gtkmm-4.8.0/subprojects/libsigcplusplus/tools/tutorial-custom-cmd.py html ../subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/libsigc_manual.xml subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/html
error : Unknown IO error
warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/html/chunk.xsl"
cannot parse http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/html/chunk.xsl
[134/2744] Generating subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/reference/html_and_tag with a custom command
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Is it perhaps a network issue? Does `wget http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/html/chunk.xsl` also fail for example?